# Reading from CSV file raising value error

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x

I tried this piece of code in Python 3.6.2

```
import csv
with open ('kk.csv') as csvfile:
    data=CSV(csvfile,delimiter=',')
for value in data:
    print(value)
```

It produced a `ValueError: I/O  operation on closed file`. I can't understand what is going on.

Comment: use `csv.reader` method to read data, not csv object.

Comment: the code that you posted is exactly the same as the one that you run? Is the indention same?

Comment: @sera yes , I've matched it with original code

Comment: So you need to add indention before : ‘for value in data:’

Comment: Yes , fine , we need to indent the for loop part

Answer (score 0):

It should actually give you a `NameError` since `CSV` is not defined.

In the documentation of the csv module, you can see from the very first example https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html how to use it:

```
import csv
with open('kk.csv') as csvfile:
    data = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in data:
        print(row)
```

If you made a mistake when copying the code here:
The `ValueError` raises because when you assign `data = CSV(csvfile)` you didn't read the content of the file yet and when you leave the context (`with open...`), the file is getting closed automatically. And then afterwards you are trying to access the content.